# Could not resolve "import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout; " in Android Studio new project

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I tried to use GridLayout as

```
GridLayout maingrid=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainGridView);
```

But it was crashing my application.
Surfing internet for the problem gave solution that i should use

```
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
```

instead of `android.widget.GridLayout;` but while using this i am getting error could not resolve v7.

Searched for this problem and got many solution to update **build.gradle** file but it also fails by build.

build.gradle file  Initially:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After updating:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}
```

please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: maybe some of the java files contain android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout; import statement at the top try to remove them manually

Answer (score 1):

### You must not add dependencies to Project/build.gradle.

**You must add them to the Project/app/build.gradle.**

You must move these to Project/app/build.gradle, in the `dependencies` block:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'
```